# Matlab plot visibility

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm building a GUI with GUIDE. I want to add a `togglebutton` to control the visibility of a plot in `axes`

```
set(handles.axes1,'visible', 'off');
```

in the button callback but the only thing it does is hiding the background of my plot (legend, grid and axis) but the stuff plotted inside remain. Why? How can I solve it?

I don't want to clean the plot because I want to make it visible again clicking again on the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only changing the visibility of the axes, not the objects (i.e. `Children`) in the axes. Instead you should set the `visible` property of the Children as well:

```
set([ax; ax.Children],'visible','off')
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should hide all the contents of the axes also.
Like this:

```
set(get(handles.axes1,'children'),'visible','off') %hide the current axes contents
```